# Access glassfish server from remote machine?

Tags: networking, glassfish, localhost

How can I access a Glassfish server installed on my local machine from another remote machine (like my phone) by using my home router?

if a web application has an address like:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapplication1
```

I want to be able to access it via a URL like for example:

```
http://192.168.1.105/webapplication1
```

where 192.168.1.105 represent the IP address of the Glassfish server.
is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Did you try and got an error? I think you'll have to specify the 8080 port, if not, it will take 80

Comment: Actually, I don't know from where to begin? do you have any suggestions please...

Comment: Currently facing the same problem, did you find any solution? I've setup all NAT configurations for my router and set the domain's IP address to my local PC's one but I still  cannot access the application for some reason...